# matching multiple conditions in racket

Tags: racket

What is the syntax for specifying multiple conditions to be matched in `match`?

For instance something like

```
(match e
  [v #:when (and a? b?)  (foo v)])
```

?

Comment: The code you posted is syntactically valid, so it’s unclear to me what you’re asking. What do you expect that code to do?

Comment: I would like to call (foo e) only when (a? e) and (b? e) both return true. Is that the way to write it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to write this is with the `match` pattern `(and (? a?) (? b?) v)`, which will check that the value matches the predicates `a?` and `b?` *and* bind the value to `v` in the body. You could also do this with a postcondition check `#:with (and (a? v) (b? v))`, but that’s generally clumsier than just using `?` patterns.

Comment: what if e is a number and I'd only like to match if it is >0 and <10? Should it look something like `(match e [v #:when (and (> v 0) (<  v 10)) ...])`?